# Sample project with unit test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Is there a project online that I can download and study that covers unit testing (Nunit or VS)?
I'm new to unit testing and thought it could be helpful to learn by real example.

Comment: You should check this question : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504737/best-unit-test-tutorials-for-beginners][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504737/best-unit-test-tutorials-for-beginners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple samples installed with NUnit already.

See the [list of NUnit samples](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=samples&r=2.5.10).

Answer (score 3):

Roy Osherove also has some useful information on his blog: [osherove.com](http://osherove.com/), especially under the Kata section.

Answer (score 0):

Sharp Architectue's [Northwind sample project has NUnit tests](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Northwind/tree/master/Solutions/Northwind.Tests)

[Their Who-Can-Help-Me sample project has MSpec tests](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Northwind/tree/master/Solutions/Northwind.Tests)

There are really tons of projects out there with nunit tests, go to github, or bitbucket, or codeplex and search for "nunit".

A bit of unsolicited advice: once you get the very basics, don't bother with the visual studio MSTest. It really has some weirdness that makes it a nightmare to work with. A bit more unsolicited advice: to run non-MSTests from within visual studio [TestDriven.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/) is indispensable.